# How can I use this HP power supply as hobby power supplly

Tags: power-supply, power

I have an HP notebook that is dead. So I thought abount using its power supply to play around with my arduino and my DC projects. So I removed the jack of the power supply [image]

This is my power supply (18v 4A)

[image]

The problem is that when I removed the jack came out 3 wires: black, white and blue. I already tried making BLACK and WHITE as + and - and leaving blue disconnected, but my circuit turns on for 3 seconds, after that it turns off for 1 second, and start again and again.

What is going on? Cant I use a notebook power supply as my hobby power supply for arduino, LEDs...?

Comment: One of the wires goes to ground. Plug the power supply into the wall and use a multimeter to measure the voltage difference of each pair of wires - you'll want to use the ones that have the nominal 18V voltage.

Comment: You should have left the *PLUG* on the power supply alone, and instead gotten the matching *JACK* out of the dead laptop. Live and learn!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is the remote sense voltage to the converter output.  It is usually fed back to a 2.5V ratiometric feedback control to keep the output voltage constant under any load with light lossy cables and 4 Amps of current , that otherwise have voltage drop.  If the supply detects a short circuit or an open circuit on sense feedback, it shuts down then the hiccup circuit retries to see if the fault condition is fixed.  ( such as a glitch during slow insertion of plug)

p.s. I have used this feature in universal chargers to devise an adjustable output voltage with a trimpot and a few other parts like in an LM317 regulator ADJ. method.

BTW  FYI and FWIW

- A connector that is on a cable is called a PLUG
- A connector that is fixed and cannot move was called a JACK until the industry (during the bra-burning women's Liberation days) of the late 60's/early 70's decided to officially change the name of JACKS to RECEPTACLES.  ( since they could be either FEMALE or MALE)   true story....
- this means you butchered your FEMALE PLUG instead of getting a matching MALE  coaxial power RECEPTACLE to interface properly .... like Dave T suggested.
  [image]

**conclusion**

- connect extra sense wire to + Dc out and it should work .
- make sense?

Comment: rather than saying it mechanically male yet electrically female centre plug , we use the terms,  pin and socket and almost "everyone" now is center positive.

Comment: If I short something in the "plug" side, can I get killed? All the 3 wires coming from the "brick" are potentially dangerous?

Comment: it is safe low V and isolated from line

Comment: thanks! Do you know if it is DC?Cause in the brick does not say AC to DC. Usually the transformers say that, right?

Comment: it is 100-320Vac or so input with ~19.5Vdc output ..read the fine print

Answer (score 4):

It may be one of those "smart" power supplies that is expecting communication with the laptop it is intended to power.  It powers up the laptop, but if nothing is heard within a few seconds, it shuts down.  The third wire is the communication channel.

If this is really what is going on, then no, you won't be easily able to use it for hobby projects.

If it's a popular model, someone may have reverse engineered the protocol or somehow obtained the specs and published them on the web.  Look around and you might find directions on how to hack the supply.

Comment: I am really sad with that :( I read some posts in the internet that if I short this "smart wire" with + or - (I am not sure which one) I could make this work. Have you ever done that? I am afraid I will destroy the power supply doing this.

Comment: just to add, macbooks tend to use this as a part of a one-wire circuit using: https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/interface/signal-line-protection-ics/signal-line-protectors/MAX9940.html ... the charger actually talks to the, in macs case, SMC which tells the charger to activate. it might be a matter of just driving that wire HIGH but I have no clue if its more complicated than that

Comment: Do you know if the wires coming from the brick (3 wires) are dangerous? Can I get killed? I think so cause I read in some forum that one of those wires is "phase" and it looks like it's dangerous right? It's not like DC + and - which is more simples, isnt?

Comment: it is simple DC out

Comment: @olin lathrop. IMHO definitely not a smart PSU or signal data wire and definitely not for any Apple products. It's Vsense to me. FWIW. This is a universal AC-19Vdc laptop supply or may be used for anything

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar Dell laptop power supply (CN-ON6M8J) and connected the blue wire to the white wire with no problems. It puts out 19.64 volts. I got the same reading before I connected the blue wire to white. But then I accidentally shorted the white and black wires and the power supply shut off and its LED went out. So I tried touching the blue wire to white (why not?). The LED came back and on the power reading was the same 19.64 volts. So I soldered the blue to the white, covered everything with shrink tubing and it is running my little LM1875-based speaker just fine. I use a simple [virtual ground](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DGTA6lxOX9k) circuit to create a positive and negative 9.x volts from the Dell supply for the LM1875. So from my actual experience, here's what works: you can either leave the blue wire unconnected to anything or connect it to white.